# Add count from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data in tableA which only holds tickets that were reopened.

```
ticket   date        owner  reopencount
123     2020-01-02   SP        1
124     2020-01-04   SP        1
234     2020-02-04   PS        1
```

And tableB has all ticket values:

```
ticket   date        owner
123     2020-01-01    SP
123     2020-01-02    SP
124     2020-01-03    SP
124     2020-01-04    SP
125     2020-01-04    SP
232     2020-02-02    PS
234     2020-02-03    PS
234     2020-02-04    PS
```

What I expect to use is tableA along with the total count of tableB in monthly counts.

Expected result:

```
ticket   date        owner  month_overall_count
123     2020-01-02    SP           3
124     2020-01-04    SP           2    
234     2020-02-04    PS           3
```

Im trying to select everything from tableA and only the count from tableB, as tableB has so much data and I don't really want to load it every time.

What I tried is :

```
select *
from tableA a
inner join (
    select format(date, 'MMM-yyyy') as month, count(*)
    from tableB
) b on format(a.date, 'MMM-yyyy') = format(b.date, 'MMM-yyyy')
```

But this will not give me field wise count if I need it later. Do I have to provide every field I'm using on tableA?

How do I get this?

Comment: Ive added it @DaleK

Comment: I don't understand the expected result. There are three tickets reopened (123, 124, 234), but your result shows only two of them (123, 234). Why? Do you pick one per month? If so, by what rule?

Comment: What do you mean "field wise count"?  The question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're looking for something like (one of) these 2 approaches.

Using OUTER APPLY

```
select a.*, isnull(b.mo_count, 0) month_overall_count
from tableA a
     outer apply (select count(*) mo_count
                  from tableB b
                  where eomonth(a.[date])=eomonth(b.[date])
                        and a.[owner]=b.[owner]) b
order by a.ticket, a.[date];
```

Using CTE

In the CTE: summarize date count (mo_count) by end-of-month date (eomonth()) and [owner] from tableB

In the Query: left join CTE on end-of-month date and [owner] to tableA to determine the month_overall_count

```
with b_month_cte(eom_dt, [owner], mo_count) as (
    select eomonth([date]), [owner], count(*)
    from tableB
    group by eomonth([date]), [owner])
select a.*, isnull(b.mo_count, 0) month_overall_count
from tableA a
     left join b_month_cte b on eomonth(a.[date])=b.eom_dt
                                and a.[owner]=b.[owner];
```

Answer (score 1):

this also could be interesting, In following way you are not forced to use `group by`

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
from tableA a OUTER APPLY
(
select  count(*) month_overall_count
 from tableB b
WHERE  format(a.date, 'MMM-yyyy') = format(b.date, 'MMM-yyyy')
) res
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.ticket,a.date,a.OWNER ORDER BY a.date desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need `union all` and `group by`?

```
SELECT TICKET, MAX(DATE), OWNER, COUNT(1) AS NUM_OF_TICKETS
FROM (SELECT ticket, date, owner FROM TABLEA 
      UNION ALL SELECT ticket, date, owner FROM TABLEB) T
GROUP BY TICKET, OWNER, dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, DATE), 0)
```

Comment: I may not be able to use union all coz i have other fields in tableA that aren't there in tableB, added an example in tableA. @Popeye

Comment: Ok, Then use the column names as updated in the answer